# Displaying partial page within a View page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a Controller/ShoppingCart which has a Action Method Index() and I created a  **Index** View Page which is strongly type and uses a model class

```
Project.Models.ShoppingCartViewModel
```

I have an another Controller/Details which has an Action Method Confirm() and I created a **Confirm** View Page which is also a strongly type and uses a model class

```
Project.Models.Confirm
```

Now all I want to do is that Create a Partial View of Index() which will use a **@model Project.Models.ShoppingCartViewModel** and display this partial page on right side of **Confirm View Page**. Both are strongly typed view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a new property to `Confirm` view model of type `ShoppingCartViewModel`

```
public class Confirm
{
   public  ShoppingCartViewModel Cart {set;get;}
   //Other Properties of your viewmodel goes here
}
```

Now in the Confirm view, Call the `Html.Partial` helper method to render the Partial view which displays shopping cart and pass the `Model.Cart` property.

```
@model Project.Models.Confirm
<h2>Confirm order</h2>
@Html.Partial("~/Views/ShoppingCart/_CartPartial.cshtml".Model.Cart)
```

Assuming your partial view is located at `~/Views/ShoppingCart/_CartPartial.cshtml` location.

Make sure you properly initialize the `Cart` property to avoid Null Reference exception (Object reference not set to an instance of object)

```
public ActionResult Confirm()
{
  var vm = new Confirm();
  vm.Cart= new ShoppingCartViewModel();
  // Load the Shopping cart property values to vm.Cart
  return View(vm);
}
```

Comment: I want to create partial view of Index() and display it in Confirm View page

Comment: @HudaNoor See my updated answer. Your Partial view should be strongly typed to `ShoppingCartViewModel`